# Oracle order by upper(colname) does not give proper results for non string columns

Tags: sql, oracle

When there is a non-string(i.e. : varchar,date) column(col1) in oracle db, if I do:

```
select * from table order by col1 asc
```

it orders properly. (ie. for date, it orders from oldest to latest, for numeric, from lowest to highest)
But if i do, `select * from table order by upper(col1) asc`
the ordering is not correct.

What is the cause for this behavior?

Comment: What is the datatype of col1? You should also add an example of "not correct". We cannot see your monitor from here

Comment: what is the result you want to achieve by using a order by upper(col) in a non-string column?

Comment: @jachguate. This is only for my understanding. No business purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPPER takes a string and returns a string.  If `col1` is anything other than a string, it will have to be implicitly cast to a string before the function is executed.  Since the output of the UPPER function is a string, however, the sort will have to use string sorting semantics, not the sort semantics of `col1`.  If `col1` is numeric, for example

- UPPER(9) returns the string '9'
- UPPER(10) returns the string '10'

The string '9' comes alphabetically after the string '10' which is, presumably, the problem you're seeing.

But if `col1` is not a string, why bother converting it to upper case in order to sort?

Comment: Thanks for predicting the problem so accurately.